# Prove that if $m|[Q(x, y) + c]$, then $m|c$.

Tags: logic, polynomials, solution-verification

I've never posted here; so I hope I'm doing it right! But, I'm asking this question out of pure curiosity and it seems so obviously true (intuitively) but I can't seem to truly prove it. I'm also relatively new to the proofs scene, but have a pretty good understanding of a lot!

Here's the actual question:

> Let $c, m \in\mathbb Z$ where $m \neq 0$ and $P(x, y) = Q(x, y) + c$  for some simple polynomials $P(x, y)$ and $Q(x, y)$ where $P(x, y)$ and $Q(x, y)$ have degree $n$ and $Q(x, y)$ has no term with degree $0$. Prove that if $m|P(x, y)$, then $m|c$.

My thoughts are that for the polynomial $P(x, y)$ every term must be divisible by $m$ in order for $P(x, y)$ itself to be divisible by $m$. And since the $c$ term cannot be combined with any other term in $P(x, y)$, then $c$ itself must be divisible, but I'm weirdly having trouble with actually proving it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see how your typesetting is awful?  Your lines are several hundred characters long.  Look how questions are typeset elsewhere and duplicate that style.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork As I said, I've never posted on StackExchange, so give me some space. No need for the aggressive comment, thanks!

Comment: @charlievans This [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial should prove helpful.

Comment: Note that $2$ divides $x^2+x$ even though $2$ doesn't divide the coefficients. But in your case, $c=P(0,0)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hmm, I definitely see what you're saying. In my specific case, I actually need m = 4, but was generalizing the problem to some integer m. Would making m > 2 make my question more substantial and worth attempting to prove since m = 2 really stunts this question?

Comment: If $Q(x,y)$ has no term of degree zero, then $Q(0,0)=0$, so $P(0,0)=c$, so if $m$ divides $P(x,y)$, then $m$ divides $c$. Has nothing to do with $m=2$ or $m=4$. But, just as an aside, $4$ divides $x^4-x^2$ for all $x$, even though $4$ doesn't divide the coefficients.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I totally agree, but what would be the proof for that? Like, I know it's true but how do I prove that? I logically know that if m|P(x, y), then m|c, but I want to be able to show it to be true if that makes sense.

Comment: What I wrote, is a proof. I proved $P(0,0)=c$. If $m$ divides $P(x,y)$, then $m$ divides $P(0,0)$, but $P(0,0)$ is $c$, so $m$ divides $c$. What more is there to prove?

Comment: So, are we OK now, charli?